# Triangle Inequality for SPD Matrix Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

We define a symmetric, positive-definite matrix $A$ to be one such that $A = A^T$ and for $x \neq 0$, $x^TAx > 0$.  If we have a norm $\|x\|_A = \sqrt{x^TAx}$, how can we show the triangle inequality?

That is, we want to show that $\|x + y\|_A \leq \|x\|_A + \|y\|_A$ as is the case for typical matrix norms.

$\|x+y\|_A^2 = (x+y)^TA(x+y) = (x^T + y^T)A(x+y) = x^TAx + x^TAy + y^TAx + y^TAy = \|x\|_A^2 + x^TAy + y^TAx + \|y\|_A^2$.

This is what I have so far, but I feel like I'm not really on the right track.  Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You essentialy have a inner product there: $\langle x,y \rangle_A = x^TAy$. Bilinearity is obvious. Symmetry comes from the fact that $A = A^T$. And $\langle x,x \rangle_A \geq 0$ and $\langle x,x\rangle_A = 0 \iff x = 0$ comes from positive-definiteness. Once you convince yourself of that, it is done: we have Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality, and with this you prove the triangle inequality for $\|\cdot\|_A$. If you want, you can copy the proofs (which are valid for an arbitrary inner product) in this context.

For example, Cauchy-Schwarz reads: $$|x^TAy| \leq \sqrt{x^TAx}\sqrt{y^TAy},$$etc.